# Downloaded windows 7, how to burn an iso image to my cd?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Downloaded windows 7, how to burn an iso image to my cd?

Comment: Why do you need it on CD?

Comment: Burn it onto a DVD.

Comment: You may want to change your question to specify DVD, since Windows 7 ISO's are only able to be burned to DVD's, since CD's are too small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a CD burning program, like the free and excellent [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/). When you run it, select "Write Image File to Disc" and it will ask you to browse for the .iso. Note that Windows 7 is a DVD image, NOT a CD image. I hope this helps.

Comment: damn, I think I got some adware with that!

Comment: Uninstall and then as you re-install, go slowly and make sure that any toolbars do not get install. If I remember correctly, it's as easy as un-ticking a checkbox. I hope that helps you.

Comment: It's ironic that Windows 7 can burn image files natively, and that you'd just have to install Windows 7 to burn the Windows 7 image onto a DVD...

Comment: Yep Adware galore.

Comment: @.@ Lots of detected virus from virustotal.com https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/7ecd4d01d5b43ec75aaf2b1747046fb46bfd2910ee80b9bf525be05dc2d92d00/analysis/

Comment: I suggest the alternative CDBurnerXP free & virus-cleaned https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/3a03a75fd7351bd2efdc7e7a028f3b19ee308db3fe15ca7e3f93249f1c3a4113/analysis/

Answer (score 5):

Burn it on a DVD, since that’s what the [instructions](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/get/installation-instructions.aspx) say.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer http://isorecorder.alexfeinman.com/Vista.htm

Comment: +1 for IsoRecorder. Works very nice for people who just need to burn an ISO - nothing fancy at all.

Comment: Great program, but it can't burn DVDs on Windows XP.

Comment: Guess I haven't used it in XP in some time. I could have swore that I had burned a DVD with it. The memory is failing me.

Answer (score 2):

No, you will need to burn it to a DVD.  You can use [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) to do so.

Comment: @.@ Lots of detected virus from virustotal.com https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/7ecd4d01d5b43ec75aaf2b1747046fb46bfd2910ee80b9bf525be05dc2d92d00/analysis/

Comment: I suggest the alternative CDBurnerXP free & virus-cleaned https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/3a03a75fd7351bd2efdc7e7a028f3b19ee308db3fe15ca7e3f93249f1c3a4113/analysis/

Answer (score 2):

The free [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en) (which are also supported on Windows XP) include `dvdburn.exe` and `cdburn.exe`, command-line DVD and CD burning programs.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on windows: CDBurnerXP - fast, easy and free: http://cdburnerxp.se/download.php

On Mac: Disk Utility handles itself pretty well

On Linux: I use Brasero

Comment: +1 for CDBurnerXP free & virus-cleaned https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/3a03a75fd7351bd2efdc7e7a028f3b19ee308db3fe15ca7e3f93249f1c3a4113/analysis/

Answer (score 0):

You need a DVD or thumb drive.